# Rspec documentation output format

Tags: ruby, rspec

According to [this piece of documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/format-option#progress-bar-format-(default)), it is possible to achieve the following output format by selecting the format `documentation`:

```
something
  does something that passes
  does something that fails (FAILED - 1)
  does something that is pending (PENDING: Not Yet Implemented)
```

Is it possible to slightly edit this so it outputs as:

```
something
  does something (SUCCESS)
  does something (FAIL)
  does something (PENDING)
```

Basically I would like the result of the test displayed no matter what - instead of just logging explicitly the failures and the pending ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by subclassing [RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/documentation_formatter.rb). Create the following file as `spec/formatters/custom_formatter.rb`:

```
class CustomFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self

  private

  def passed_output(example)
    format_output(example, 'SUCCESS', :success)
  end

  def pending_output(example, _message)
    format_output(example, 'PENDING', :pending)
  end

  def failure_output(example)
    format_output(example, 'FAILED', :failure)
  end

  def format_output(example, status_text, code_or_symbol)
    RSpec::Core::Formatters::ConsoleCodes.wrap(
      "#{current_indentation}#{example.description.strip} (#{status_text})",
      code_or_symbol
    )
  end
end
```

Then run the specs using this:

```
rspec --require formatters/custom_formatter --format CustomFormatter
```

Instead of `--require formatters/custom_formatter`, you can also require the formatter on `spec/spec_helper.rb`, e.g.

```
require_relative 'formatters/custom_formatter'
```

Then you only need to run this:

```
rspec --format CustomFormatter
```

If you want `CustomFormatter` to be the default formatter, you can add the command line options to [`.rspec` configuration file](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files) at your project root. Here's how it should look like:

```
--require spec_helper

--require /path/to/custom_formatter.rb
--format CustomFormatter
```

With that, you no longer need to specify any command line arguments to use `CustomFormatter`.

Documentations and references:

- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/formatters/custom-formatters
- http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Formatters
- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/formatters/documentation_formatter.rb

Comment: That works brilliantly for `SUCCESS` (not sure about `PENDING`, however it gives me that error whenever a test fails: `failure_output: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`.

I could fix it by editing the signature of the method you provided as follows: `def failure_output(example, _message)`

Comment: @Pauline Glad that you managed to get it working despite the error. Looks like you're using an older version of RSpec. Starting from RSpec 3.5, that method is changed to just 1 argument. Here's the commit that changed it: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/227e7cae419eee104764a8c9cfbf20b911cb63aa

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the existing RSpec formatters, but you can [create your own](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters)

> When RSpec's built-in output formatters don't, however, give you everything
> you need, you can write your own custom formatter and tell RSpec to use that
> one instead. The simplest way is to subclass RSpec's BaseTextFormatter, and
> then override just the methods that you want to modify.